# List all Calls made on Teams using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to retrieve all calls that a certain user did using Teams Applocation. I tried Microsoft Graph but it did not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Which documentation did you research on your requirement? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.